# Get current reachability state with RestKit 0.20

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

So I'm using RestKit 0.20.0 and getting reachability changes via this block:

```
[objectManager.HTTPClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable) {
        self.isConnectedToInternet = NO;
    }
    else {
        self.isConnectedToInternet = YES;
    }
}];
```

I'm storing the state with a property called isConnectedToInternet, but this is only getting set when reachability changes. I don't see a method or property on the RKObjectManager or the AFNetworking version that RestKit uses in order to just get current reachability state, like this:

```
[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic, assign) AFNetworkReachabilityStatus networkReachabilityStatus
```

On the `AFHTTPClient`.